# MVC4 Razor Modal not showing value passed into custom Javascript function with the onclick event handler

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

The modal opens. The "Id" value is displayed in the readonly textbox with id = "Id". But the Description value does not display in the readonly textbox with the id = "Description". I stepped through the code and the correct value is present in the function on the master view. However, it is not displaying in the modal. Am I missing something? Why is the value not passing to the Description id in the partial?

Partial

```html
@model AutoClickItOnline.Models.AdminViewModels.DeleteSubTypeViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteSubType", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="Id" class="text-dark">Subscription Type ID</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubTypeId, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = true, id = "Id" })
            <label for="Name" class="text-dark pt-2">Descripiton</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = true, id = "Description" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Delete Subscription Type</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Javascript:

```js
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#user_table').DataTable({
                "scrollY": "50vh",
                "scrollX": true,
                "autowidth": false
            });

        });

        function DeleteSubType(id, Description) {
            $('#Id').val(id);
            $('#Description').val(Description);
            $('#DeleteSubTypeModal').modal('show')
        }
    </script>
}
```

```html
Main View:

@model AutoClickItOnline.Models.AdminViewModels.SubscriptionTypeTableViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SubTypes";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row py-5">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="modal fade" id="newSubTypeModal">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h2 class="modal-title">New Subscription Type Entry</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                @{
                                    Html.RenderPartial("/Views/Admin/AddSubTypePartial.cshtml", new SubscriptionType());
                                }
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="DeleteSubTypeModal">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h2 class="modal-title">Delete Subscription</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                @{
                                    Html.RenderPartial("/Views/Admin/DeleteSubTypePartial.cshtml", new AutoClickItOnline.Models.AdminViewModels.DeleteSubTypeViewModel());
                                }
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                    <h2 class="pr-2">Subscription Type Manager</h2>
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ml-auto my-2 text-light text-center d-none d-md-block" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newSubTypeModal"><i class="fa fa-plus text-light pr-1"></i>Add New Subscription Type</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ml-auto my-2 text-light text-center d-sm-none" style="max-height:50px;" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newSubTypeModal">ADD NEW</a>
                </div>
                @if (Model.Message != null)
                {
                    <div class="text-danger">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Message, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                }
                <hr />
                <table id="user_table" class="display small-table table-bordered border-dark" style="width:100%;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="font-size:11px; min-width:195px;">Id</th>
                            <th style="font-size:11px;">Description</th>
                            <th style="font-size:11px;">Length</th>
                            <th style="font-size:11px;">Cost</th>
                            <th style="font-size:11px;">Active</th>
                            <th style="font-size:11px; min-width:100px;">Date/Time Created</th>
                            <th style="font-size:11px; min-width:60px;">Created By</th>
                            <th style="font-size:11px; min-width:105px;">Date/Time Modified</th>
                            <th style="font-size:11px; min-width:65px;">Modified By</th>
                            <th style="font-size:11px;">Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.SubscriptionTypes)
                        {
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size:11px">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubscriptionTypeId)</td>
                            <td style="font-size:11px">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</td>
                            <td style="font-size:11px">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Length)</td>
                            <td style="font-size:11px">$@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cost)</td>
                            @if (item.Active)
                            {
                                <td style="font-size:11px">Yes</td>
                            }
                            @if (!item.Active)
                            {
                                <td style="font-size:11px">No</td>
                            }
                            <td style="font-size:11px">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateTimeCreated) UTC</td>
                            <td style="font-size:11px">@AdminHelpers.GetUsersName(item.CreatedBy)</td>
                            <td style="font-size:11px">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateTimeModified) UTC</td>
                            <td style="font-size:11px">@AdminHelpers.GetUsersName(item.ModifiedBy)</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="X" onclick="DeleteSubType('@item.SubscriptionTypeId', '@item.Description'); return false;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi, your code seems ok to me .. But, you have given `return false;` to your function ..why?

Comment: @Swati return false; is an old way of preventing the default browser behavior.

Comment: Found it!. Both partials rendered in the view contain elements with the same id. Did not know that ids are explicit properties and JavaScript will assign to the first instance of the specified id.